# Routing is not working properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my product view I have created a page display.html.erb and I need to show all my products here when I click showall link from the /product page.

Below are my code

```
routes.rb
get "/products/display" => "products#index"
 resources :products
```

products/index.html.erb

```
<table>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">


          <td>
            <%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'list_image') %>
          </td>

          <td class="list_description">
            <dl>
              <dt><%= product.title %></dt>
              <dd><%= truncate(strip_tags(product.description),
                               :length => 80 ) %></dd>
            </dl>
          </td>

          <td class="list_actions">
            <%= link_to 'Show1', products_display_path(product) %><br />
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %> <br />
            <%= link_to 'Destroy', product,
                        :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
                        :method => :delete %>
          </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>

  </table>
```

products.display.html.erb

This page will contain same content as products/index.html.erb page except edit, show and destroy options

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: I don't see a link to showall in your file.  Also, what is your controllers code?

Comment: Can I offer some constructive criticism about this question? Your title states that rails routing itself, rather than your code, is somehow broken. It's probably not rails that is broken. The first answer below shows why your code isn't working. I'm not saying that rails is somehow perfect: it isn't. But when you, I, or anyone else thinks they've found a fatal flaw in the basic functionality of something that's working fine for many other people, we're probably wrong. Also, as noted by Max above, your question doesn't contain an actual question. Can you edit to show what your exact problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Rails Routes documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) (2.10.2)

```
#routes.rb
resources :products do 
   collection do 
     get "display", :to => "products#index"
   end
end
```